# How to separate two elements retrieved from a database

Tags: php, html

I have retrieved two pieces of data from a database: review and movie_title, how do I go about displaying each value in it's own DIV element?

This is how I am sending the data to another page.

```
<td align="left"><a href="review.php?id='. $row['review'] . $row['movie_title']  .'"> Read    Review </a>
```

This displays fine using   the below code.

```
<?php

    $review = $_GET['id'];

    echo $review;

    ?>
```

But I would like to display the review in one DIv and movie_title in another Div on the same page how is this done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
echo '<a href="review.php?id='. $row['review'] . '&title=' . $row['movie_title']  .'">Read Review </a>';
```

On the next page:

```
<div><?=$_GET['id']?></div><div><?=$_GET['title']?></div>
```

Comment: I get this error from the above idea: Undefined variable: row

Comment: I edited the code, because I didn't really understand what you wanted to do in the first hand. Please try again.

Comment: Yeah it worked second time around sorry. How does the '&title=' work ?

Comment: I mean when calling my Variable on the second page by using $_GET why am I using ['title'] instead of ['movie_title'] ?

Comment: Because you have the querystring parameter "title" defined in the originating link. You can change it to "&movie_title=", but you need to change the second page to reference it vie $_GET['movie_title']

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
<td align="left"><a href="review.php?review='. $row['review'] . '&movie_title='. $row['movie_title']  .'">Read Review</a>
```

end in the page redirect:

```
<div><?php echo $_GET['review']; ?></div>
<div><?php echo $_GET['movie_title']; ?></div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain how '&movietitle=' has replaced movie_title ?

Answer (score 1):

Pass $row['review'] and $row['movie_title'] as different parameters and get those parameters

eg:

```
<td align="left"><a href="review.php?id='. $row['review'] . '&movie_title=' . $row['movie_title']  .'"> Read    Review </a>
```

then write a DIV block

```
<div>
   <?=$_GET['id']?>
</div>
<div>
   <?=$_GET['movie_title']?>
</div
```

But you may have to handle your parameters in different way if it is already working i guess!!

>